# Feed the drain pan drain hose through the indirect drain pipe, so that the washer drain pan can slide with the washer & dryer stack

Tags: drain, stacked-washer-dryer

Contemplating a solution to the problem of a small laundry closet on an upper floor and a tall and heavy front-loading stack that would barely fit through the door. It seems impossible to slide the stack in (or out) over the lip of the drain pan. According to the manual, the stack height is 79.5", the drain pan spec says it has 1.64" sides, and I measured the door frame as 80.2" high. There may be some give in the pan, but I don't know if I can count on it.

The drain pan would be connected to a 1" PVC pipe on the rear wall that simply drains to the ground floor, and it is not connected to any drains directly.

Question is, could I attach a 5 to 6' hose of some kind to the drain pan outlet, place the pan outside the closet, simply insert the other end of the hose into the PVC drain pipe, install the stack on top of the pan, then slide the whole thing into place and the hose hopefully gets pushed deeper into the drain pipe?

I guess for this to work, the hose diameter can't be very big, and the flow rate would be reduced. Would this diminish the benefit of having a drain pan?

[image: Laundry closet with washer drain pan]

Comment: 1) Got pics?
2) Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Washer drain pans are typically for emergency spills, not for use as a primary drain.

Comment: @Huesmann Yes, the emergency one, I'm not talking about the primary drain. There is a standpipe in the outlet box for that. The pan is affixed to that outlet on the wall. But I'm imagining the pan would have a hose or some tubing affixed that then slides into the outlet.

Comment: Rock (crib) them on to two by four shorts to get them into pans. Two in the pan; two underneath. But your problem is it wouldn't fit through the door. Options are: no pan, scratch the floor, or dissemble the door frame :(

Comment: A hose small enough to slip down a 1"od pipe will have a reduced flow rate, so that's why you want a water alarm (or two) thrown in there. Try and make the outflow hose as short as possible to prevent/minimize kinking as it goes down the pvc.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate That's my worry. Maybe combining your advice with Triplefault's, I can tie a weight to the end with a long string and send it down the drain, use that to pull the hose into the pipe. I'll look into the water alarms, thanks.

Comment: Where will your pan drain to?

Comment: There is a PVC in that back wall (you can see the cutout in the baseboard in the photo) that opens to the ground floor., not connected to an actual drain. I guess I'll get a larger pan for downstairs and some water alarms, but worst case, it will flood the concrete ground floor, instead of all the hardwood floors and ceilings in between.

Answer (score 2):

Sliding the pan on the floor with a washer and dryer stacked on it will be heavy and may scratch up the floor. I have put a bath towel under heavy items getting slid on a floor to protect the floor. In a laundry room with the possibility of water getting into the towel and starting mold, though, the towel may not be a good idea to leave in place. You may test slightly  leaning the stack to see if the towel can be pulled out after the stack is made. If so, then the towel could be used while sliding the stack. Also, be tender with sliding on the drain pan, as it's plastic and could break if forced.

The drain pan hose could be made longer so someone on the ground floor can gently pull on it as the stack is slid into the room, then the drain pan hose won't have a tendency to kink up as the stack is slid in. The hose then could be cut shorter or left full length as needed to reach a drain location. Test that water will actually drain through whatever hose you decide to use. Flow rate can be great if the tub of the washer failed catastrophically and let all the water out at once, or if the water supply fails full-open.

A different idea: you have 11/16" space above the stack to use. You may be able to assemble the stack inside the closet: drain pan first, washer next. Then put a bath towel on the washer so the surface could be protected, then put the dryer up top. Once the dryer is in place, lean the dryer a bit to remove the bath towel.

Comment: The stacking kits have screws in the back. The installers told me they couldn't reach those, or any of the hook ups to install them in place.

Comment: That is a tight space if one needs to work in the back. Try the towel on the floor and long-enough hose to pull from downstairs.

Comment: @mkayaalp - You still have to get back there to hook it up. They need to send the 120 pound guy, not the 300 pound one. And it needs to be flexible drain line (one inch liquid tight EMT?) so it can be shoved to the side wall, so that who ever the sorry mf is who's going to do it can squeeze back there. Just checking... there's power, water, drain, and exhaust... right? - Consider getting something smaller. When it breaks it's this same process in reverse: you waiting for the guy who can fit and is willing to work bent-over backwards while sideways.

Comment: @Mazura Yes, their solution is me finding 4+ ft cords, supply and drain hoses, flex duct, so they'll connect it outside. Even without the pan, they won't push it in (liability thing, in case connections get bent).